# jQuery .cycle() is invisible in Webkit browsers [Safari / Chrome] on first load (after refresh everything works fine!)

Tags: jquery, css, safari, cycle, invisible

I'm using [jQuery cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) to implement a slideshow effect.

You can click on any slideshow image to slide to the next one.

This works fine in all browsers. Only in Safari, something really weird happens. Upon the first page load, no slideshow images are displayed at all! After reloading the page (either by refreshing or by hitting the 'Go' button next to the address bar), everything works like it should.

What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

---

**Update:**

I'm using the latest versions of both jQuery and the Cycle plugin. Here's the code I'm using to invoke .cycle():

```
if (1 < $('.image-list li').size()) {
 $('.image-list').cycle({ fx: 'uncover', speed: 200, timeout: 4000, next: $('.image-list li') }).addClass('image-list-cycle');
}
```

Comment: are there any errors or some other clue that could help us troubleshoot your problem?

Comment: This seems to happen in Google Chrome as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added some more information to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just google for this error, you will find plenty of people having troubles with the jQuery plugin applied to images. Troubles happens usually in terms of position and showing.

My feeling is that sometime the script is run just before the images are loaded and the used width/length values for cycling the images are wrong.
I would suggest you to add something like this to your page (adapt classes and names to your needs):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('.image-list li').each(function({$(this).css({
        [SET HERE POSITION, WIDTH, ETC]});});
      $('.image-list').cycle([OPTIONS]);});
</script>
```

Comment: I hardcoded the height and width of the LIs in my CSS, and that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Using `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` seems to help also.

Comment: Makes sense, since `window.onload` only fires after all images have loaded (so their dimensions are known).